# How can I use a for loop to simplify my code?

Tags: r

I want a dataframe with a list of the next values:

```
a <- Data[1,2]
b <- Data[2,3]
c <- Data[3,4]
d <- Data[4,5]
df <- data.frame(c(a,b,c,d))
```

I need to repeat this many times so I thought maybe there is a simple way to write this code.

First I thought something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
for(i in 1:4){
  df <- data.frame(Data[i,1+i])
}
```

Wanted result:

[image: Wanted result]

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You say you want a dataframe (and your variable is called `df`) but the desired result you’ve shown is a *vector*. Which is it?

Comment: Ah I see, I mean a dataframe. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
diag(as.matrix(Data[1:4,-1]))
```

Thus

```
df = data.frame(number = diag(as.matrix(Data[1:4,-1])))
```

Comment: @Irene232545 If you think this answer help, please consider accepting it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need a `for` loop<sup>1</sup>. Instead, [you can subset your data using a matrix index](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html):

> When indexing arrays by [ a single argument i can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of x; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of i.

```
index = matrix(c(c(1 : 4, 2 : 5)), ncol = 2L)
df = data.frame(number = Data[index])
```

Replace `1 : 4` and `2 : 5` with your desired *i* and *j* indices.

If it’s more convenient to work with paired (*i*, *j*) indices, you can also generate a matrix for them, you just need to pass `byrow = TRUE`:

```
index = matrix(c(
    c(1L, 2L),
    c(2L, 3L),
    c(3L, 4L),
    c(4L, 5L)
), ncol = 2L, byrow = TRUE)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As a general rule, `for` loops are a *last resort* in R. They have valid uses, but they often make code more complex than necessary. In many cases (as above) you can get away without any kind of iteration. If you need iteration, your first port of call should be a specific, suitable vector algorithm (e.g. `cumsum`). And if there’s no suitable algorithm, you next go to a higher-order list function (such as `lapply`/`vapply`/`Reduce`/`Filter` or the equivalent functionality from the ‘purrr’ package).

Only when none of these operations are suitable should you resort to a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the code below using `col` + `row`

```
> df <- data.frame(number = Data[col(Data)-row(Data)==1])

> df
     number
1 0.8983897
2 0.1765568
3 0.9919061
4 0.1255551
```

**Data**

```
> Data
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.2655087 0.89838968 0.2059746 0.4976992
[2,] 0.3721239 0.94467527 0.1765568 0.7176185
[3,] 0.5728534 0.66079779 0.6870228 0.9919061
[4,] 0.9082078 0.62911404 0.3841037 0.3800352
[5,] 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
          [,5]
[1,] 0.9347052
[2,] 0.2121425
[3,] 0.6516738
[4,] 0.1255551
[5,] 0.2672207
```