# How can I simplify this code to make a data.frame?

Tags: r

I need to code a piece that I have to repeat many times from a to z (instead of a to e). Is there a simple method I could use to code this piece?

```
a <- 1
b <- a*Data[1,1]
c <- b*Data[2,1]
d <- c*Data[3,1]
e <- d*Data[4,1]

df <-data.frame(c(a,b,c,d,e))
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate [your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67123112/how-can-i-use-a-for-loop-to-simplify-my-code) less than an hour after your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `cumprod`

```
> df <- data.frame(number = cumprod(c(1,Data[1:4,1])))
> df
      number
1 1.00000000
2 0.26550866
3 0.09880212
4 0.05659913
5 0.05140377
```

**Data**

```
> set.seed(1)

> (Data <- matrix(runif(16),4))
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.2655087 0.2016819 0.62911404 0.6870228
[2,] 0.3721239 0.8983897 0.06178627 0.3841037
[3,] 0.5728534 0.9446753 0.20597457 0.7698414
[4,] 0.9082078 0.6607978 0.17655675 0.4976992
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `Reduce` and `accumulate`

```
df <- data.frame(number = Reduce(`*`, c(1, Data[1:4,1]), accumulate = TRUE))
```